# Does SharePoint support Excel spreadsheets linked to each other?

Tags: excel, sharepoint-online

I have a master excel sheet on sharepint (called "masterfile.xlsx") that I want to link to another Excel file (called "file-test.xlsx") in different folders on sharepoint.

I need that the "masterfile.xlsx" reflect any changes in the worksheet "file-test.xlsx"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your formulas in your master workbook to include the URL to the online content. The links will not update when you display the master workbook in the browser (online), but can be updated by opening the master workbook in a desktop Excel.

```
='https://yourDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yourSite/Shared Documents/[yourExcelFile.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

You can link them using Excel's PowerQuery:
  https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/linking-two-excel-worksheets-in-sharepoint-online/cfe2741b-f09b-4d22-93ee-37218261a4d4

You can relink the files using Mapped Drives (mapping a drive letter to a SharePoint library), but this is not a good solution unless all users of the Excel file are willing to map to the library using the same drive letter.